# how to show image on button click event on web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on asp.net, here I want to show IMAGE on button click event, Image should appear at line no.3, but image is appearing after completion of line no 10(i.e. after completion of Button1_Click() event)

what will be the solution to make image appear on execution of line 3?

```
#default.aspx
1. <asp:FileUpload CssClass="SelectFile" ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
2. <br />
3. <asp:Button CssClass="gen" ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Generate" />
4. <br />

#default.aspx.cs
1.protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
2.{
3.    Image.Visible = true;
4.    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
5.    {
6.       ////////
7.       code
8.       ////////
9.    }
10.}
```

what will be solution to make Image appear at line no.3 on web page, rather than appearing after completion of line no 10(i.e. after completion of Button1_Click() event)

Comment: I think you want something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76111151/razor-pick-a-local-image/76111708#76111708

Answer (score 1):

You need to do that on the client, not the server.

This JavaScript selects the image that you want to display by the id of 'myImage' - you would need to change that to the image's Id.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myClosure(){
        var myImage = document.getElementById('myImage');
        myImage.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
</head>


<body>
```

Call it like this:

```
<asp:FileUpload CssClass="SelectFile" ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
2. <br />
3. <asp:Button CssClass="gen" ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="myClosure()"  Text="Generate" />
4. <br />
```